# Which wordpress plugin increases the size of tag as per more number of posts on it?

Tags: plugins, text

I have a blog on `wordpress`. I have several posts on `WATIR`, had few on `manual testing` and `framework`

That time when I visited my blog I saw that text "WATIR" appears as giant heading, but rest are small. Later I wrote more on "Manual Testing", Now I am seeing that "WATIR" is biggest, "Manual Testing" is smaller and rest remain smallest.

Note that: WATIR, Manual Testing and Framework are tags and not categories.

How is this happening, which plugin is used to do this?

Comment: which plugin is used to do what? please be more specific, I can guess that you are talking about the tag cloud widget, but it is better to be sure ;)

Comment: To add to @MarkKaplun *I have a blog on wordpress*. Does this mean your site is hosted on wordpress.com? If so, you need to contact their support as wordpress.com related questions are off topic here :-)

Comment: hello, it's wordpress tag cloud, in-built widget. which tag has more posts will shown larger, and this chain continues from larger to smaller.